# Rails 3 Nested Forms with datamapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datamapper

i have two models:

```
class MeetingPoint

    include DataMapper::Resource

    belongs_to :profile

    property :id, Serial
    property :lat, String

end
```

and

```
class Profile

    include DataMapper::Resource
    has n, :meeting_points

    property :id, Serial

    property :distance, Text
    property :created_at, DateTime
    property :updated_at, DateTime

end
```

Now I create a form to edit the profile and the meeting_poing:

```
= form_for @profile do |f| 

    = f.text_field :distance
    = f.fields_for  @profile.meeting_points do |ff|
        = ff.text_field :lat
    = f.submit
```

But when I want to save the values I get always the error:
"The attribute 'meeting_point' is not accessible in Profile"
in controller
@profile.update(params[:profile])

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a [plugin](https://github.com/snusnu/dm-accepts_nested_attributes/) (dm-accepts_nested_attributes) which will fix this issue -

Similar issue and more details discussed [here](http://datamapper.lighthouseapp.com/projects/20609/tickets/1308-update-fails-when-supplied-with-nested-attributes)